# Why is Vue not adding view count to a post?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

###### Problem

---

I'm building a post website with a view count.
I am also using firebase. I added the view count so if you click on one of the posts (`playlists`in the code) it should add one view to the post.

As you can see the view count is added in the `p` tag inside the `router-link`. It is also added in the `PlaylistDetails` component. The problem is that it updates the view count in the `p` tag but not in the `PlaylistDetails`.

So when you click on the router-link, the p tag will update and it will bring you to the playlistdetails component, but there it won't update.

This is my code:

###### The View Count with Button

---

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link
      :to="{ name: 'PlaylistDetails', params: { id: playlist.id } }"
      @click="handleViews"
    >
      <div>
        <button>test</button>
        <p>{{ playlist.views }}</p>
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import useDocument from "../composables/useDocument";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default {
  props: ["playlist"],
  setup(props) {
    const { updateDoc } = useDocument("playlists", props.playlist.id);
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleViews = async () => {
      const res = await updateDoc({
        views: props.playlist.views++,
      });
    //   await router.push({
    //     name: "PlaylistDetails",
    //     params: { id: props.playlist.id },
    //   });
      console.log("add view");
    };

    return {
      handleViews,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

###### The PlaylistDetails component

---

```
<p>{{ playlist.views }}</p>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be mutating props. Also your code doesn't update anything in `PlaylistDetails`?

Comment: You need to emit the event so that the parent that provides that data has the view count updated instead. See https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow

Comment: Thanks! I hope it works

Comment: @EmielVandeVeire can you share if Terry's suggested solution worked for you?